# Nativebase - customise a component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

I just want to change the color of the line between each `ListItem` in a `List` to red. I think I have to do a custom theme to overwrite the default `ListItem`.

Trying:

```
import getTheme from '../../../native-base-theme/components'
import listItemTheme from '../../../native-base-theme/components/ListItem'

import {
  List,
  ListItem,
  Text,
  Left,
  Body,
  Right,
  Button,
  Container,
  Header,
  Title,
  Content,
  StyleProvider
} from 'native-base'

const styles1 = {
  'yourTheme.CustomComponent': {
    borderColor: 'red', 
    borderBottomWidth: 1
  }
}

Categories = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Categories)

export default connectStyle('yourTheme.CustomComponent', styles1)(Categories)
```

each ListItem:

```
const renderCategoryRow = (props, item) => {


  return (
    <StyleProvider style={styles1}>
    <ListItem
      style={{
        ...styles.labelHeight
      }}
      icon
      onPress={() => props.toggleShowSubcategories(item)}>

      <Left>
        <Icon
          style={styles.icon}
          name={item.icon}
          size={20}
          color={item.iconColor} />
      </Left>
      <Body style={{...styles.labelHeight

      }}>
        <Text style={{
          ...styles.label,
          color: '#7c6a4d'
        }}>{item.label}</Text>
      </Body>
      <Right style={styles.labelHeight}>
        <Eicon style={styles.arrow} name="chevron-right" size={30} />
      </Right>
    </ListItem>
      </StyleProvider>
  )
}
```

Getting error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluation
>   'variables/listBtnUnderlayColor')

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error by using an empty `getTheme()` in the `<StyleProvider>`:

```
const renderCategoryRow = (props, item) => {
  const styles1 = props.style;
  return (

<StyleProvider style={getTheme()}>
<ListItem

  style={{
    ...styles1

  }}
  icon
  onPress={() => props.toggleShowSubcategories(item)}>
```

Then I edited the actual `components/ListItem.js` theme file which caused any `<ListItem>` within the `<StyleProvider>` to take on those changes in the `ListItem.js` file.

Then did this throwaway custom theme to make it happy when using `connectStyle()`:

```
// Define your own Custom theme
const customTheme = {
//backgroundColor: 'black'
height: 55,
borderBottomColor: 'red'

  }


export default connectStyle('customTheme', customTheme)(Categories)
```

...and it worked.